Android Studio (Koala) java app build issue
When I try to build my android java app I get this class conflict error
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar -> jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21.jar -> jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)

I am not using the CollectionsJDK8Kt class in my project. Still I m getting this error. I m working in Android Studio Koala version.
I m hanged in this issue I can not upload my app on google play console. I need immediate help
